# iPhone clock precision xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, precision, clock

I have an app that needs to use the iPhone/iPad clock and needs to be absolute precise. I have time differences of almost 2 seconds every 10/12 hours with a real quartz watch.

Is there any way of having a "perfect" clock? Seems strange that you have to deal with this kind of  delays/advance.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the iPhone/iPad is the device that's imprecise, not your watch?

Comment: Absolutely. Put your device in airplane mode. Bring a quartz stopwatch and start the iPhone/iPad system stopwatch at the same time as the real quartz one. Soon you will see the delay.

Comment: I'm not sure what that proves. Could just mean that your stopwatch is the inaccurate one.

Comment: I have tested with 4 or 5 different "real" watches. The iPhone / iPad seems to use internet to sync the clock, and found other posts assuring different accuracies depending on carier ... And, what about if you don't have internet?

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485072/accurate-timing-in-ios  HOW can we possibly have an accurate timming when the delay depends on carriers, syncs or devices?