# Need to schedule a timertask in native code for android ndk development?

Tags: android, c++, c, linux, android-ndk

am developing an android app that calls a native method which inturns spawns a thread.
Now in this thread i need to time a piece of code to be executed. for that i need to start a timer and once that timer expires that code block should execute and then again the timer should be started... please give me ideas... am a newbie.. searched online so much... didnt get anything relevant...

One Note: i dont want to make that thread sleep and handle using alarm signal... what i need is a timertask in native code say C or C++.. and winc++ wont work cause android is based on linux...

Comment: Hi, how did you resolve it ? How do you use alarms in nkd ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is exactly what you are looking for, but I use clock_gettime in my project to handle timers. Here is a detailed thread about timing in NDK: [Accurate POSIX thread timing using NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17099162/accurate-posix-thread-timing-using-ndk)

Comment: let me try what you have said and ill also check out that other thread... thank you